# R-Markdown: Print text variable as it is in R-markdown (Word file)

Tags: r, r-markdown

How can I print a character variable in RMarkdown as normal text? The texts should not be shortened and all of them should be printed (not just 16 for example) and not as a table (no headers). It could also be a bullet list.

```r
---
title: "Title"
author: "The Name"
output:
  word_document: default
---
```

```r
text <- c(
  
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu libero justo. Ut mauris nisl, tristique in tellus non, tristique sagittis turpis. Donec ipsum dolor, volutpat sagittis sapien id, feugiat viverra mi. Quisque sodales ligula consequat lorem sollicitudin cursus. Integer cursus in erat vel bibendum. Etiam elit ipsum, blandit vitae ullamcorper ac, imperdiet eget nunc. Sed tempor tempus sem eget imperdiet. Nulla elementum purus commodo magna viverra mattis. Nam facilisis sed enim sit amet imperdiet. Etiam sed ullamcorper justo. Donec porta erat vel sapien tempor sollicitudin. Phasellus odio augue, elementum non laoreet at, ultrices sed ipsum. Morbi a pharetra dolor.",
  
  "Mauris ac metus feugiat arcu volutpat luctus. Nullam tempor ligula at dui condimentum, id feugiat nunc mattis. Vivamus sit amet turpis a orci vestibulum scelerisque quis vel arcu. Etiam risus ligula, fringilla vestibulum arcu eget, accumsan semper urna. Donec at ligula placerat, malesuada lacus a, pretium ligula. Aenean iaculis sem a leo posuere, ac ultrices ex accumsan. Curabitur sed consectetur felis. Vivamus sed lacus elementum, semper tortor eget, placerat augue. Morbi non nulla eleifend, vestibulum tellus et, consectetur purus.",
  
  "Nullam metus sem, finibus et massa quis, tempus scelerisque velit. Nullam facilisis, dui eu dapibus bibendum, mauris nibh tristique turpis, non iaculis felis leo sed metus. In sodales mauris id risus luctus finibus. Cras vel pretium massa. Nullam interdum non odio a tincidunt. Maecenas rhoncus risus non augue semper aliquam. Proin porta efficitur justo, pellentesque molestie mauris condimentum aliquet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eu lorem euismod, ornare diam vel, dignissim justo. Maecenas placerat magna id quam finibus sollicitudin sed id neque.",
  
  "Mauris porta sed diam nec sollicitudin. Mauris pharetra leo tellus, lacinia aliquam libero finibus vitae. Quisque volutpat leo sed imperdiet congue. Sed vel consequat mauris, in tempus nibh. Nam non tortor rhoncus, efficitur dolor et, porttitor sapien. Praesent gravida mattis est sed pharetra. Mauris sollicitudin augue at libero ultrices maximus. Aliquam aliquam viverra lorem eget dictum. Nunc ut molestie mauris.",
  
  "Mauris tempor a quam sit amet elementum. Mauris vulputate consectetur odio, sed pharetra nisi tempus sit amet. Vestibulum vel ex et lectus gravida cursus quis nec turpis. Phasellus eget libero eleifend, hendrerit leo a, finibus magna. Curabitur ultricies, lacus eget semper blandit, mi libero tincidunt nibh, a rutrum diam sem at nisi. Vivamus semper dui velit, vel mollis nunc aliquam ac. Suspendisse vitae cursus risus. Pellentesque elit lacus, congue a commodo eu, ultricies nec nibh. Integer non diam lectus. Proin eu odio facilisis, tempus sem ac, molestie augue. Proin hendrerit tincidunt rhoncus. Proin gravida erat eget elit viverra, id congue nisl tristique.",
  
  "Vivamus augue sapien, dictum lacinia feugiat vel, aliquam in nisi. Donec dictum semper ipsum, ac volutpat tortor commodo quis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Integer pharetra magna quis lacus volutpat, sit amet sodales mi imperdiet. Fusce tincidunt ultrices pellentesque. Sed molestie nunc et velit fringilla euismod. Ut eu dolor vel mauris dignissim faucibus a laoreet lacus. Maecenas feugiat, dui non hendrerit blandit, justo eros interdum sapien, ut lacinia nulla felis ac augue. Curabitur aliquet lectus ut erat faucibus feugiat. Maecenas dui nibh, consectetur sed lorem semper, pharetra finibus arcu. Praesent a ultricies sapien, venenatis vehicula magna. Vivamus in ornare sem.",
  
  "Nam varius ultricies blandit. Quisque id risus neque. Aliquam imperdiet, sem vitae sollicitudin egestas, neque eros scelerisque orci, ac congue turpis justo id neque. Nullam egestas elit vulputate tincidunt vulputate. Aliquam venenatis dignissim odio, at accumsan metus dapibus non. Nunc vel ultrices mauris. Phasellus convallis magna sit amet ante scelerisque, nec aliquam lectus molestie. Curabitur quis accumsan turpis, ac ornare ante. Praesent massa quam, suscipit in ornare eu, ullamcorper eget enim. Donec ultricies nisl ac accumsan egestas. Aliquam porttitor arcu rhoncus facilisis faucibus. Sed non ex a turpis maximus elementum at sit amet neque.",
  
  "Duis tortor lectus, pulvinar vel nisl a, rutrum ullamcorper ex. Integer quis massa turpis. Curabitur eu hendrerit leo, commodo feugiat nisl. Fusce et massa at velit viverra pellentesque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi a nisi consectetur, feugiat eros at, blandit purus. Curabitur lacus neque, euismod vitae dolor quis, mollis feugiat risus. Aliquam lorem mauris, sodales laoreet ligula porta, convallis facilisis turpis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec tempus, mauris sed congue facilisis, risus nunc tempor risus, eu imperdiet quam felis sed neque. Aenean egestas ex in risus elementum, vitae varius erat efficitur. Nam egestas rhoncus mollis.",
  
  "Nam eu mauris mollis est finibus semper ut tincidunt arcu. Integer faucibus, orci non varius ornare, turpis mauris tempor erat, semper pulvinar justo urna non enim. Ut volutpat sem tortor, ac volutpat neque porttitor vitae. Fusce rutrum nisi a venenatis aliquam. Suspendisse tempor et turpis vitae cursus. Sed enim sapien, fringilla id dictum et, dapibus nec lectus. Nulla elit lectus, viverra nec metus a, auctor auctor mauris. Praesent efficitur scelerisque lectus, vel auctor magna porttitor ac. Suspendisse dapibus justo sed congue suscipit. Integer luctus sollicitudin eros. Fusce quis vulputate sem, at fermentum metus. Aliquam pulvinar tellus eget sapien sollicitudin, vitae pretium velit tempor. Maecenas sit amet urna massa. Nunc at auctor justo. Fusce quis nulla egestas tellus sagittis condimentum. Suspendisse at urna nisi.",
  
  "Donec finibus, augue non porta euismod, eros orci dapibus purus, et mollis arcu nisl eget velit. Nullam laoreet mattis nisi, eu porta arcu ultricies ut. Sed dignissim tincidunt odio, nec euismod nibh pulvinar eget. Vivamus rhoncus sed urna at feugiat. Maecenas viverra elementum odio, quis efficitur metus volutpat id. Duis at mollis enim. Aenean pretium ipsum ut lobortis porta. In porta, eros vel dignissim mattis, magna sapien hendrerit quam, quis egestas sapien justo vel sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut felis ut nisi efficitur posuere. Fusce pulvinar felis a diam tristique, in dapibus nulla iaculis.",
  
  "In ac justo nulla. Mauris pharetra laoreet elit, eget faucibus tortor blandit nec. Suspendisse rhoncus tristique augue, nec congue ante. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi dolor lacus, sodales eu velit at, pretium pretium nunc. Donec varius bibendum dolor. Suspendisse potenti. Donec tincidunt ut erat quis convallis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed tempor ullamcorper nisi eget consequat. Maecenas commodo ligula aliquam leo vehicula tristique. Suspendisse potenti. Donec malesuada sagittis semper. Suspendisse faucibus nisl pretium luctus posuere.",
  
  "Maecenas laoreet nisl egestas sem bibendum varius. Vivamus dignissim, arcu hendrerit tempus varius, nulla sapien rhoncus leo, sit amet ultricies magna libero vel ante. Duis elit risus, semper ac urna quis, pulvinar rhoncus lacus. Sed sed accumsan mi. Curabitur non dapibus lacus, sed aliquet leo. Proin fermentum mauris quam, quis varius nisl accumsan in. In pellentesque sit amet erat quis ullamcorper. Sed non nisi eu purus iaculis efficitur. Nullam consectetur lectus lectus, nec vulputate felis hendrerit sit amet.",
  
  "Quisque sagittis nunc id lorem cursus lobortis. Suspendisse aliquam dignissim neque non convallis. Aliquam ac risus in enim ultrices varius a a sem. Integer nec tempor diam. Aliquam faucibus posuere elit, ac consectetur diam ornare blandit. In auctor viverra dignissim. In semper purus sapien, nec auctor arcu lacinia ut.",
  
  "Nunc augue mi, condimentum sed facilisis sed, tincidunt in libero. Fusce et eros sit amet sapien ultrices pretium ut eu diam. Etiam tempus sed neque sit amet condimentum. Fusce orci lacus, mollis non iaculis non, cursus ut nibh. Morbi fringilla nisi in felis vulputate fermentum. Donec auctor quis libero vitae tristique. Aenean dui diam, elementum in semper at, euismod in urna. Nullam eleifend odio et mi sodales, ac placerat purus hendrerit. In tempor eu velit nec pulvinar. Maecenas eros lectus, pharetra nec ante eget, rhoncus consequat arcu. In finibus vehicula nunc vel maximus.",
  
  "Ut est orci, semper id ullamcorper ac, tristique ut nulla. Cras mauris dolor, ultrices a consectetur nec, feugiat eget nisi. Proin blandit vulputate blandit. Sed faucibus vehicula tortor vel congue. Sed commodo mauris vel varius euismod. Quisque eu nulla malesuada nisi volutpat iaculis non sed dui. Morbi libero sem, bibendum non feugiat ac, porta non dui.",
  
  "Suspendisse bibendum dapibus turpis, ut congue mauris pellentesque at. In mattis eros lectus, luctus molestie arcu fringilla ut. Vestibulum mauris urna, lacinia id dapibus in, efficitur ut est. Duis mollis eros enim, ut sollicitudin ligula feugiat quis. Etiam non sem id lacus dignissim mattis et in odio. Donec efficitur neque nunc, a dapibus lacus tristique at. Suspendisse id porta risus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut consequat turpis diam, a tincidunt metus bibendum vitae.",
  
  "Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut congue vitae velit ut convallis. Phasellus nec pulvinar turpis. Curabitur accumsan neque ac lectus vehicula rhoncus. Proin sit amet nisi id diam cursus pharetra. Vestibulum a massa metus. Quisque in eleifend est. Aliquam iaculis sem et metus imperdiet iaculis. Vestibulum sagittis quam et lectus euismod, et porta nibh mattis. Pellentesque dictum quam quis orci lacinia, a tempor magna pharetra. Praesent blandit, velit quis pellentesque egestas, arcu sapien eleifend tortor, eu scelerisque eros leo in est. Nullam nec accumsan nisl. Sed et est eros. Quisque vel ex tortor.",
  
  "Pellentesque nec quam at dolor rutrum auctor. Duis tincidunt massa sapien, ut elementum orci consequat commodo. Ut nec cursus quam. Maecenas eu ante tincidunt, condimentum tellus non, vestibulum lacus. Aenean odio ipsum, accumsan in nibh eget, tempus egestas velit. Donec orci libero, ultrices a eleifend ullamcorper, tincidunt ut quam. Duis non aliquam tortor, vel porta lectus. Etiam lacinia velit sed mattis iaculis. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque maximus cursus nisl nec egestas. Vivamus ac nisl aliquam purus fringilla condimentum. Vestibulum nulla sem, rutrum eget ultrices mollis, interdum id mi. Curabitur dignissim diam non nulla ornare, eu ornare neque pulvinar. Proin vitae urna eros. Ut in nisi eu quam pulvinar tincidunt ut in erat.",
  
  "Quisque aliquam nisi leo, ut facilisis neque pellentesque nec. Nullam rutrum nibh metus, vitae ullamcorper massa cursus sed. Cras pulvinar, magna vel egestas congue, nisi nibh tincidunt felis, molestie euismod ante tellus nec enim. Maecenas sed pretium felis, eget elementum leo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam id mi sed dui faucibus vehicula. Nunc sed ex aliquam, fringilla ipsum quis, ullamcorper tortor. Etiam at nibh nec orci posuere imperdiet at sit amet sapien. Cras tristique accumsan mi vitae finibus. Curabitur at ligula mauris. Suspendisse id massa sem. Ut vehicula porttitor mauris, quis faucibus libero.",
  
  "Aliquam molestie volutpat condimentum. Vestibulum fermentum quam eget arcu scelerisque, sed sollicitudin quam tincidunt. Praesent eget rutrum risus, et consectetur diam. Duis ultricies nisi a mi tincidunt, non fringilla dolor finibus. Fusce non ligula convallis, ultricies lorem eu, dignissim dui. Phasellus vulputate dapibus bibendum. Fusce fringilla eros a nulla feugiat, quis efficitur tortor bibendum. Nulla congue leo vitae condimentum tincidunt."
  
)

df <- data.frame(text = text) %>% as_tibble()

df
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `cat` and chunk options `results="asis"` should do the trick:

````
```{r, results = 'asis'}
df$text |> cat()
```
````